# Binding custom property with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, binding, entity

I am building a C# application using the Entity framework.

I have an Entity which was created from my database which has fields "Price" and "Quantity".

Using a partial class declaration I created a custom property "SubTotal" as follows:

```
partial class Detail {
  public decimal Subtotal {
    get
    {
      return Price * Quantity;
    }
  }  
}
```

The thing is, I use a lot of DataBinding in my application.

Somewhere, I use an `IBindingList<Detail>` as `ItemsSource` for a ListView.

When I modify (using code-behind) some elements of the list, the quantity and price, the listview is updated properly.

However, the Subtotal is not updated.

I think that it's because something is done automatically by the entity framework to notify that something has been changed, but I don't know what to add to my custom property so that it behaves the same way.

Could you help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UI doesn't know that the value of `Subtotal` is changed. Implement [`System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx), and then raise the `PropertyChanged` event to let the UI know that `Subtotal` has changed when either `Price` or `Quantity` has changed.

For example:

```
partial class Detail : INotifyPropertyChanged {

   public decimal Subtotal 
   {
      get
      {
         return Price * Quantity;
      }
   }  

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
   {
      if (PropertyChanged != null)
      {
          PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
      }
   }
}
```

Then when `Price` or `Quantity` is changed, you'd call `NotifyPropertyChanged("Subtotal")`, and the UI should update the displayed value of `Subtotal` appropriately.

Comment: Well, the class EntityObject already implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. It the auto-generated code-behind, they use `ReportPropertyChange(...)` for notifications. However, if I use `ReportPropertyChanged("SubTotalTL")`, I get and exception "The property 'SubTotalTL' does not have a valid entity mapping on the entity object."

Comment: @JSMaga Well, from the code you've posted, `SubTotalTL` doesn't exist in your `Detail` class, so it makes sense that you'd get an exception. What happens when you call `NotifyPropertyChanged("Subtotal")`?

Comment: Arf, I just had to use `PropertyChanged("SubTotalTL")`. I was looking for `NotifyPropertyChanged`. It works now. Sorry I should have come up with that myself.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is to call the OnPropertyChanged method:

```
OnPropertyChanged("CustomPropertyName")
```