# Summing BindingList elements

Tags: c#, .net, binding

This question is a follow-up from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069232/binding-custom-property-with-entity-framework).

Basically I have a grid which contains several object called `Details`.

Each of them are created using the Entity Framework.

The binding is working well within the grid, even the custom properties `SubTotal` on each line is binded properly and everything is fine.

The only thing I want to do know, is to have a textbox at the bottom of the window show the total.

The source of the datagrid is a `BindingList`, so I assigned this list as the `Data Context` of the TextBox, and I applied a Converter for the binding with the code as follows:

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
       BindingList<Detail> sDets = (BindingList<Detail>)value;

       return sDets.Sum(x => x.Quantity*x.Price);
    }
```

However, this doesn't work. That is, when I edit the list, the changes are not updated in the text box.

I though the BindingList were supposed to handle this wasn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add a change event for it to know that something is different. IMO it would be easier to forget binding here, and just handle the ListChanged event directly.

Comment: Ok I thought it would be heavier in terms of performance but I guess it's fine.